How to inject/retrieve an application property inside a static method
I'm using Spring Boot. I have a "Service" class with no constructor that has only static methods and uses ThreadLocal to store some values and return those values when requested.
I want this to be enabled only when an application property allows it. How do I retrieve that property in this context.
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.NONE)
public class FooService {
    private static final ThreadLocal<Foo> foo = new ThreadLocal<>();
    
    public static void initialiseEvaluationLog(Foo newFoo) {
        if (isFooServiceEnabled()) {
            foo.set(newFoo);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isFooServiceEnabled() {
        return ${feature.enable.foo.service};  // I need help here
    }

    public static void cleanFoo() {
        foo.remove();
    }

    public static Foo retrieveFoo() {
        return foo.get();
    }
}

I tried having a private static field and injecting it with @Value
@Value("${feature.enable.foo.service}")
private static Boolean isFooServiceEnabled;

I tried this solution too and it still didn't work: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-static-field
There's no constructor so I can't really inject anything can I?
Is there any way I can get that property programatically?

When you say "environment property", do you mean property (e.g. defined in an application.yml file), or environment variable? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Testing would be easier if this static class were a Bean instead. Does it have to be static?

Your service still has a public no-arg constructor. Setting the Lombok annotation to access = AccessLevel.NONE just means Lombok won't generate a no-arg constructor. Java will still create a default public no-arg ctor.

FooService isn't a Spring bean, so Spring does not know about it and can not set the value. That means @Value annotation is useless there. One way is writing a Spring bean that will set the needed property when the bean was created:
@Component // define it as spring component
public class HelperClass {

    @Value("${feature.enable.foo.service}")
    public boolean featureEnableFooService;

    @PostConstruct // executed when Spring bean was created
    void initStaticField() {
        FooService.isEnabled = featureEnableFooService;  // set static property
    }

}

and rewrite FooService as
public class FooService {

    public static boolean isEnabled;

    private static boolean isFooServiceEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    // other stuff here

}

In application properties set
feature.enable.foo.service = true

and verify that all that works:
@SpringBootTest
public class StaticTest {

    @Autowired
    HelperClass helperClass;

    @Test
    void testStatic() {
        assertEquals(helperClass.featureEnableFooService, FooService.isEnabled);
    }

}


To keep everything together you could make HelperClass a static inner class of FooService and then you can keep FooService.isEnabled private.

The Baeldung article assumes that your class is a bean as well as having a static property, and therefore that the @Value annotation will be activated by Spring. Your class is not a bean, however, so you need to use some bean to provide it for you. You could put it on a inner class just to keep everything together:
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.NONE)
public class FooService {
    private static boolean isEnabled;
    private static final ThreadLocal<Foo> foo = new ThreadLocal<>();
    
    public static void initialiseEvaluationLog(Foo newFoo) {
        if (isEnabled) {
            foo.set(newFoo);
        }
    }

    public static void cleanFoo() {
        foo.remove();
    }

    public static Foo retrieveFoo() {
        return foo.get();
    }

    @Component
    public static class FooServiceEnabler() {

        @Value("${feature.enable.foo.service}") 
        public void setEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
            FooService.isEnabled = isEnabled;
        } 
    }

}

Note that this assumes you have @ComponentScan for the package containing this class.
However it might well be easier to make this class not static at all. Why fight the system? It is easier to set things up and test them when you use beans.

It is fairly easy reading environment variables with vanilla Java:
String yourVariable = System.getenv().get("YOUR_VARIABLE");

The reason you couldn't use the Baeldung article is that you confused properties and variables.

Ok, I think I got confused again, I do actually mean property... I'll edit again
